# Can't reach from another device with Browsersync

Tags: node.js, gulp, device, browser-sync

For several days now, I can't reach the external address Browsersync gives.
When I try to reach from the browser of another device, nothing happens. I'm currently using Windows 10 on the local machine.

Today I tried with another machine using Windows 7 and it's working well, then it's not a issue from router-level.
When I launch Browsersync with the machine using Windows 7, I can reach the external address by using any device I want.

Someone has any suggestion ?

Comment: No one has any idea about it ? I can't reach the external IP from another device. Please help me.